# jquery $.post not working in Internet Explorer, MVC Post IEnumerable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Have searched around for a while now and tried some different suggested solutions but none of them works for me.
I have a webpage that administers group membership and when they search on a member to add and get multiple results a table is displayed with users they can choose from. My solution right now is to have a javascript execute when they click the submit button which will send a post with all the users checked

```
function Submit() {
    var users = "";
    $(".checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            if (users == null || users == "") {
                var headerParent = $(this).parents()[1];
                var targetChild = $(headerParent).find(".hiddenFullName").val();
                users = targetChild;
            }
            else {
                var headerParent = $(this).parents()[1];
                var targetChild = $(headerParent).find(".hiddenFullName").val();
                users = users + ";" + targetChild;
            }
        };
    });
    $.post("Groups/MultipleSearchHit", { 'users': users });
};
```

The locating of the targetChild etc are working fine and the users variable contains what I am after, but in Internet Explorer the $.post just wont execute.....
Another acceptable solution would be how to post an IEnumerable of the model my View has based on the checkboxes...

Here is my table, so for the "MVC way" I guess I would like all the rows that have the checkbox checked to be posted in an IEnumerable?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
<tr>
    <th>
        #
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Givenname)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
    </th>
    <th>
        Send email?
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="~/Images/user_ico_small.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
            <input name="Username" type="hidden" value="@item.Username" />
            <input class="hiddenFullName" name="FullName" type="hidden" value="@item.FullName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Givenname)
            <input name="Username" type="hidden" value="@item.Username" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
            <input name="Surname" type="hidden" value="@item.Username" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)
            <input name="Department" type="hidden" value="@item.Username" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
            <input name="Company" type="hidden" value="@item.Username" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="NotifyEmail" class="form-control">
                <option value="false">No</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" width="89" class="checkbox"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop (not `foreach`) or an `EditorTemplate` for you model and strongly type the checkbox to a model property. Then you can post back your model using `form.serialize()`. And what is the purpose of all those other hidden inputs? And since you don't eve do any thing in the success callback, what is the purpose of using ajax?

Comment: The hidden input is the full DN of the user, dont want to output LDAP://CN=Johan,DC=contoso,DC=com to the user i use it to add the user to the group without the need to keep track of what domain they come from. I dont do anything in the success callback because I want my controller to redirecto me.
Okay can you give me an example of how to accomplish it the "Model" way?

Comment: If you want to redirect, then do not use ajax (the while purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page and will never redirect). Simply generate your form correctly and do a normal submit. And the hidden inputs I am referring to are the ones named `Surname`, `Department` and `Company` which your setting to the value of `Username` (they are pointless).

Comment: And what is the dropdownlist for - you never post a value for it so its not clear what your really trying to do. What data do you want to get in the controller - just a collection of the `FullName` values or do you want other values as well?

Comment: Could someone just provide me an example of how to post back all the Models in the the IEnumerable with modified values I would be gratefull